# Is there a built in Kotlin method to apply void function to value?

Tags: kotlin, utility-method

I wrote this method to apply a void function to a value and return the value.

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(f: (T) -> Unit): T {
    f(this)
    return this
}
```

This is useful in reducing something like this:

```
return values.map {
    var other = it.toOther()
    doStuff(other)
    return other
}
```

To something like this:

```
return values.map { it.toOther().apply({ doStuff(it) }) }
```

Is there a language feature or method like this already build in to Kotlin?

Comment: Just for my education, the point of `doStuff` here is to evaluate it for its side-effects, a bit like the `peek` method in Java 8 streams?

Comment: Yes, I think it's similar to `peek`, but applied to an object instead of a stream. It also reminds me of RxJava's `doOnNext()`, but again, applied to an object instead of a stream. And the point of `doStuff` is really up to the user, but in my case it's to add to `other` a cache.

Comment: Related issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6903. Feel free to vote or star to get updates.

Comment: the `apply` function is now part of the Kotlin standard library.  See answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. My solution is basicly the same as yours with a small refinement:

```
inline fun <T> T.apply(f: T.() -> Any): T {
    this.f()
    return this
}
```

Note, that `f` is an extension function. This way you can invoke methods on your object using the implicit `this` reference. Here's an example taken from a libGDX project of mine:

```
val sprite : Sprite = atlas.createSprite("foo") apply {
    setSize(SIZE, SIZE)
    setOrigin(SIZE / 2, SIZE / 2)
}
```

Of course you could also call `doStuff(this)`.

Comment: A similar library method is going to be added to M13: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6903

Comment: the `apply` function is now part of the Kotlin standard library.

Answer (score 4):

Apply is in the Kotlin standard library:  See the docs here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html

Its method signature:

```
inline fun <T> T.apply(f: T.() -> Unit): T (source)
```

> Calls the specified function f with this value as its receiver and returns this value.