# Scope functions apply/with/run/also/let: Where do their names come from?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, higher-order-functions, scoping

There are quite a few blog posts (like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/examining-kotlins-also-apply-let-run-and-with-intentions)) on usages of the standard library functions `apply`/`with`/`run`/`also`/`let` available that make it a bit easier to distingish when to actually use which of those pretty functions.

For a few weeks now, the official docs even provide guidelines on that topic finally: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#using-scope-functions-applywithrunalsolet

Nevertheless, I think it is pretty hard to memorize the function's **individual use cases** by the **function names**. I mean, for me they seem to be interchangeable, why isn't `let` called `run` for instance?

Any suggestions? I think the names aren't very expressive which makes it hard to see the differences at first.

Comment: These are very situational functions. You'll memorize them by using them when need it. For ex: I wanted to know how to continue after ?. using nullables and I found `let`. Learned it on the spot. Same with `with` or 'also'. Once you know they exist, you'll get into the cases when you know there is something but you don't remember which is. Several trips to the docs will ensure you'll know them in the future. At least this is how I'm doing it

Comment: This isn't really a problem for me either. I always know one of them that can be used in particular situations. But the thing is, the function names do not really tell what they really do.

Comment: Well, you know the hardest thing in programming...

Comment: A while ago I made a fuss when you answered a question that had been asked before and was later closed as a duplicate. I used to be overly passionate about keeping this site clean and everything that comes with it and it resulted in me acting not-so-nice to you. I have since learned to let go of this excessive passion and I apologize for acting the way I did. You do great work on here and your contributions are much appreciated, keep it up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's an **unofficial** overview of how the names seem to have come to be.

### let

[`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is inspired by the functional programming world. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression)

> a "let" expression associates a function definition with a restricted scope

In FP languages like Haskell you can use `let` to bind values to variables in a restricted scope like so

```
aaa = let y = 1+2
          z = 4+6
          in  y+z
```

The equivalent (albeit overly complicated) code in Kotlin would be

```
fun aaa() = (1+2).let { y -> 
              (4+6).let { z ->
                y + z
              } 
            }
```

The typical usage of `let` is to bind the result of some computation to a scope without "polluting" the outer scope.

```
creater.createObject().let {
    if (it.isCorrect && it.shouldBeLogged) {
        logger.log(it)
    }
}

// `it` is out of scope here
```

### with

The [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) function is inspired by the `with` language construct from languages like [Delphi](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=with) or [Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) (and probably many others) where

> The with keyword is a convenience provided by Delphi for referencing
>   elements of a complex variable, such as a record or object.
>
> ```
> myObject.colour := clRed;
> myObject.size   := 23.5;
> myObject.name   := 'Fred';
> ```
>
> can be rewritten :
>
> ```
> with myObject do
> begin
>   colour := clRed;
>   size   := 23.5;
>   name   := 'Fred';
> end;
> ```

The equivalent Kotlin would be

```
with(myObject) {
    color = clRed
    size = 23.5
    name = "Fred"
}
```

### apply

[`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) was added to the stdlib relatively late in the milestone phase (M13). You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659271/615306) question from 2015 where a user asks for exactly such a function and even suggests the later to-be-used name "apply".

In the issues https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6903 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6094 you can see discussions of the naming. Alternatives like `build` and `init` were proposed but the name `apply`, proposed by Daniil Vodopian, ultimately won.

`apply` is similar to `with` in that it can be used to initialize objects outside of the constructor. That's why, in my opinion, `apply` might as well be named `with`. However as `with` was added to the stdlib first, the Kotlin devs decided against breaking existing code and added it under a different name.

Ironically, the language Xtend provides the so-called [with-operator `=>`](http://jnario.org/org/jnario/spec/tests/integration/UsingXtendSWithOperatorSpec.html) which basically does the same as `apply`.

### also

[`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) was added to the stdlib even later than `apply`, namely in version 1.1. Again, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6903 contains the discussion. The function is basically like `apply` except that it takes a regular lambda `(T) -> Unit` instead of an extension lambda `T.() -> Unit`.

Among the proposed names were "applyIt", "applyLet", "on", "tap", "touch", "peek", "make". But "also" won as it doesn't collide with any keywords or other stdlib functions and its usages (more or less) read like English sentences.

Example

```
val object = creater.createObject().also { it.initiliaze() }
```

reads a bit like

> Creater, create the object and **also** initialize it!

Other stdlib functions whose usages read a bit like English sentences include [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) and [`takeUnless`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-unless.html) which also were added in version 1.1.

### run

Finally, the [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) function actually has two signatures. The first one `fun <R> run(block: () -> R): R` simply takes a lambda and **runs** it. It is mostly used for assigning the result of a lambda expression to a top-level property

```
val logger = run {
    val name = System.property("logger_name")
    Logger.create(name)
}
```

The second signature `fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R` is an extension function which takes an extension lambda as parameter and seems to also be named "run" for symmetry reasons. It also "runs" a lambda but in the context of an extension receiver

```
val result = myObject.run {
    intitialize()
    computeResult()
}
```

I'm not aware of any historical reasons for the naming.

Comment: Thank you! For me, `with` does makes sense as it is, because the receiver is passed as the first argument, which we do something **with**, thus I wouldn’t like `apply` to be named `with`

Comment: For more clarification in kotlin android:

https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/kotlin-scope-functions-b84e37644d32

Answer (score 10):

I strongly recommend to read this [blog](https://typealias.com/guides/understanding-let-also-run-apply/) in order to understand all of these scope functions.

Some keys of these blog:

1. **LARA functions**

[image]

Following the first letter of each, you get the acronym “LARA”.

2. **Code Comparison**

[image]

3. **Common use cases**

   - [Transforming](https://typealias.com/concepts/let/#transformation) an object - let()
   - [Create, pass, and evaluate](https://typealias.com/concepts/also/#create-pass-and-evaluate) - also()
   - [Initialize and execute](https://typealias.com/concepts/run-with-receiver/#initialize-and-execute) - run()
   - [Initialize an object](https://typealias.com/concepts/apply/#initializing-an-object) for assignment - apply()
4. **With**

`with()` is functionally the same as the extension function version of `run()`, so it's well-suited to the use case of [Initialize and execute](https://typealias.com/concepts/run-with-receiver/#initialize-and-execute). More [information](https://typealias.com/concepts/with/).

Answer (score 9):

Adding to the @kirillRakhman answer:

A major part in the naming process was (still is) fluent reading experience in major use cases.

`with`:

```
with(database) {
    open()
    send()
    close()
}
```

`apply`:

```
val v = View().apply {
    width = 3.0
    height = 4.0
    register(this)
}
```

`also`:

```
db.users()
    .filter { it.age > 18 }
    .map { account }
    .also { log(it) }
```

IMHO it doesn't really work with `let` well. After all, it was taken from "those scary FP languages". But I often think of it as a sort of `Let's do this!` construct. Like below you could read the code as `let's print it!`:

```
account.map { it.owner }.sumBy {age}.let { print(it) }
```

Comment: I do recall a discussion we had about `let` on slack recently ;-)

Comment: @s1m0nw1 the more I discuss `let`, the less I am satisfied with its naming :P

Answer (score 0):

Summary of Scope functions:

**let**: Used to check nulls, also better than simple null check in multi-threading case

**also**: same as 'let'  but it doesn't return the last line as 'let', instead 'also'  will return the object it was called on and 'not the last line!'

**apply**: helpful function to modify objects, if you want to change in properties of the objects, and it uses 'this' instead of 'it' as we work inside the class of the object

**run**: equivalent to 'apply', but it won't return the object it was called, instead it will return the last line

**with**: same as 'run' but a different signature.